# Fazer um update de varios campos e valores em uma mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

Estou fazendo um sistema muito simples para controle de estoque, e na parte de editar os produtos, eu estou fazendo desta forma: faço uma query num banco de dados, e listo campos de texto com o nome dos produtos e a quantidade respectiva, como na imagem em anexo:
[image: Sistema de estoque]

Desta forma o usuário poderia alterar tudo o que quisesse, e ao clicar em enviar, fazer um update de todos os campos no banco, de acordo com a ordem certa.

A minha dúvida é: Como fazer isso ?

Atualmente meu formularia está assim:

```
<form action="update_pcs.php" method="POST">
            <label>Peça</label>
            <label for="txtQtd" id="qtd">Qtd.</label>
            <br/>
                <?php foreach($rtn as $pcs){ ?>
                        <input type="text" name="txtNome[]" id="txtNome" value="<?=$pcs['pc_nome']?>" />
                        <input type="text" name="txtQtd[]" id="txtQtd" value="<?=$pcs['num']?>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="txtId[]" id="txtId" value="<?=$pcs['id']?>" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                <?php } ?>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="btnEnvia" />
    </form>
```

E o arquivo update_pcs.php, que deve fazer o update:

```
<?php

    include_once 'mdl.php';
    $conexao = new modelDB();

    $qtd = $_POST['txtQtd'];
    $nom = $_POST['txtNome'];
    $id = $_POST['txtId'];

    $dados = array('nome'=>$nom,
                    'qtd'=>$qtd,
                    'id'=>$id);

    /*isso faz com que o campo nome de $dados seja um array, qtd outro array e id outro*/
    foreach($dados as $dado){

        /* Atualmente estou fazendo desta forma, mas não está funcionando */
        $nomeAt = $dado['nome'];
        $qtdAt = $dado['qtd'];
        $id = $dado['id'];  

        $conexao->alteraDb("update pcs_estq set pc_nome ='{$nomeAt}', num = '{$qtdAt}' where id = '{$idAt}'");
    }
```

A função está correta pois quando troco as variaveis por valores, funciona corretamente. Acredito que esteja errando na ideia de passar um array, mas nao sei como fazer. Não sei se estou fazendo da forma correta, ou se estou fazendo a melhor forma. Se puderem me ajudar serei grato, obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema está no array `$dados` e na iteração dele pelo foreach. As variáveis`$qtd`, `$nom` e `$id` são arrays. Logo quando você faz:

`$dados = array('nome'=>$nom,
                    'qtd'=>$qtd,
                    'id'=>$id);`

Está criando um array de array. Para que seu foreach funcione do jeito que você escreveu, modifique o formulário desta forma:

```
<?php $count = 0; foreach($rtn as $pcs){ ?>
                    <input type="text" name="txtDados[<?= $count ?>][nome]" id="txtNome" value="<?=$pcs['pc_nome']?>" />
                    <input type="text" name="txtDados[<?= $count ?>][qtd]" id="txtQtd" value="<?=$pcs['num']?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="txtDados[<?= $count ?>][id]" id="txtId" value="<?=$pcs['id']?>" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
            <?php $count++; } ?>
```

Dessa forma, terás apenas um array, `$txtDados`. No arquivo `update_pcs.php`, troque a variável $dados para `$dados = $_POST['txtDados'];`

Comment: Encontrei uma solução parecida com a sua no stack em inglês, porém a sua foi ligeiramente melhor, obrigado e parabéns ! Espero um dia poder retribuir.